# How can I change WordPress Jobify theme header color?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, themes

hey everyone I'm working on a WordPress theme called Jobify, I would like to change the header color. The theme comes with a color setting but it build to change the overall color of the site to the selected color

my header code below:

```
/**
 * 4.0 Header
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    .site-header {
    box-shadow: inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .10) 0 -4px 0;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.3s;
    transition:         all 0.3s;
    }

    .site-header .container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1.5em;
    }

    .site-branding {
    float: left;
    }

    .site-branding:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .site-header.open .site-branding {
    float: none;
    }

    .site-title {
    font: bold 22px/normal 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .primary-menu-toggle {
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .site-header.open .primary-menu-toggle {
    float: none;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    }

    .site-description {
    display: none;
    }

    .primary-menu-toggle i:before {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    }

    .site-primary-navigation,
    .site-header.open .primary-menu-toggle.in-header {
    display: none;
    }

    .site-header.open .site-primary-navigation {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 2em;
    }

    .site-header.open .primary-menu-toggle,
    .site-header.open .primary-menu-toggle span,
    .site-header.open .primary-menu-toggle i {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .site-header.open .primary-menu-toggle span {
    padding-top: 4px;
    }

    .site-primary-navigation #searchform {
    margin: 1em 0;
    }

    .site-primary-navigation #searchform div {
    position: relative;
    }

    .site-primary-navigation #searchform input[type="text"] {
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .10);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0;
    }

    .site-primary-navigation #searchform button {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    line-height: 39px;
    font-size: 23px;
    background: none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    }

    .site-primary-navigation #searchform button:hover {
    border: 0;
    }

    .site-header.open .site-primary-navigation .nav-menu-primary {
    margin: 2em 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .nav-menu-primary li {
    margin: 8px 0;
    }

    .nav-menu-primary li a {
    font: 400 20px 'Varela Round',sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .nav-menu-primary li .sub-menu {
    padding-left: 1em;
    }

    .nav-menu-primary li .sub-menu a {
    font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Comment: Without the HTML code or the class/ID of the DOM element that you want to change its colour, it will be hard to help you. Also, if I am not mistaken, it seems that the Jobify theme is a commercial theme and the author (Astoundify) provides [online documentation](http://jobify.astoundify.com/) and [one to one support](https://support.astoundify.com/).

Comment: http://jobify.astoundify.com/article/402-modify-your-websites-colors